# DrawTextEx not working with DT_RIGHT and Arial font

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2007, delphi-xe3, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I’m having an issue with DrawTextEx. When using Align = DT_RIGHT and font “Arial”, the text exceeds the rectangle.

This is the code I used to reproduce the issue:

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  LRect: TRect;
  LString : string;
  LMetaCanvas: TMetafileCanvas;
  LAlign: integer;
  LParams: TDrawTextParams;
begin
  LMetaCanvas := TMetafileCanvas.Create(Image1.Picture.Metafile, 0);

  LRect := Rect(10, 10, 200, 200);

  LMetaCanvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  LMetaCanvas.Brush.style := bsSolid;

  LMetaCanvas.Rectangle(LRect.Left, LRect.Top, LRect.Right, LRect.Bottom);

  LMetaCanvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';
  LMetaCanvas.Font.Size := 10;
  LMetaCanvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  LMetaCanvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  LString := '111111111111111112';

  LParams.cbSize := SizeOf(LParams);
  LParams.iTabLength := 0;
  LParams.iLeftMargin := 0;
  LParams.iRightMargin := 0;
  LParams.uiLengthDrawn := Length(LString);

  LAlign := DT_RIGHT or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_NOCLIP;

  DrawTextEx(
    LMetaCanvas.Handle,
    PChar(LString),
    Length(LString),
    LRect,
    LAlign,
    @LParams);

  LMetaCanvas.Free;
end;
```

Without DT_NOCLIP, the characters which are outside the rectangle aren’t even displayed.

I’m using Delphi 10.2 on Windows 10 Pro, but I’ve been facing this issue also on Delphi XE3 and Delphi 2007.

Edit: I tried to use DT_CALCRECT, but I’m not sure this is the correct way… This is the code I used:

```
  LAlign := DT_RIGHT or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_NOCLIP or DT_CALCRECT;

  DrawTextEx(
    LMetaCanvas.Handle,
    PChar(LString),
    Length(LString),
    LRect,
    LAlign,
    @LParams);

  LAlign := DT_RIGHT or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_NOCLIP;

  DrawTextEx(
    LMetaCanvas.Handle,
    PChar(LString),
    Length(LString),
    LRect,
    LAlign,
    @LParams);

  LMetaCanvas.Free;
end;
```

After first call to DrawTextEx, LRect became (10, 10, 120, 26), which makes it smaller than how I configured it at the beginning (10, 10, 200, 200). The text is drawn aligned to the left (I guess that’s because LRect was changed in order to fit the text) and still, without DT_NOCLIP I can’t see the last numbers.

Edit: The project where this issue emerged requires a `TMetaFileCanvas` (for other purposes) and uses `DrawTextEx` to display amounts (which have to be aligned to the right), so unfortunately I can’t change canvas type, alignment or text. Using a different font like Arial Unicode MS (which doesn’t seem to have issues) would mean changing a huge amount of existing reports, so I’d rather avoid this solution..

Comment: Looks like quite a corner case. "1" as the character, Arial as the font, and a metafile as the device context... Change any one of the three and I can't find any combination that misaligns. One would guess there are though.. Looks like an MS problem to me.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I agree, this looks like a corner case, but this piece of code represents a real issue which emerged quite often and represents a big problem when users see a truncated amount of money. Sometimes they don’t even realize the amount is incorrect because the truncation cuts a whole digit instead of a part of it.. I thought that could be a MS problem too but I was hoping to solve it with some workaround in Delphi… Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Changing the font would be the logical action. May not make any difference if users are able to choose their font though. Gluing some invisible character to problem characters might be a workaround. I tried and found out the "zero width space" works ok f.i. E.g.: `LString := StringReplace(LString, '1', '1'#$200B, [rfReplaceAll]);` (don't know if D2007 would have a problem with it). Reproducing the problem with only api calls and tagging the question with winapi might also help.

Comment: .. AAMOF a single zero width space is enough, it doesn't even matter where it is. E.g.: `LString := LString + #$200B;` Perhaps it forces to bypass some kind of optimization. Or who knows what...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz adding a zero width space at the end of `LString` worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SertacAkyuz suggested, adding a zero width space at the end of `LString` solved the issue.

```
LString := LString + #$200B;
```